# How can I get the value of a LivaData<String> at once in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-livedata

`savedRecordFileName` is a variable of `LivaData<String>`, I hope to get the value of `savedRecordFileName` at once in Code A.

You know that LiveData variable is lazy, maybe the value of `savedRecordFileName` is null in `binding.btnStop.setOnClickListener { }`, so the code in `binding.btnStop.setOnClickListener { }` will not be fired when the value of `savedRecordFileName` is null.

I hope that the code in `binding.btnStop.setOnClickListener { }` can always be fired, how can I do?

BTW, I think the Code B is not suitable because the value of `savedRecordFileName` maybe changed by other function.

**Code B**

```
binding.btnStop.setOnClickListener {
   mHomeViewModel.savedRecordFileName.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
        val aMVoice = getDefaultMVoice(mContext,it)             
        mHomeViewModel.add(aMVoice)  
   }
}
```

**Code A**

```
class FragmentHome : Fragment() {

    private val mHomeViewModel by lazy {
        getViewModel {
            HomeViewModel(mActivity.application, provideRepository(mContext))
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {        
       ... 
       binding.btnStop.setOnClickListener {
            mHomeViewModel.savedRecordFileName.value?.let{
                val aMVoice = getDefaultMVoice(mContext,it)             
                mHomeViewModel.add(aMVoice)                
            }
        }
        ...
        return binding.root
    }

}


class HomeViewModel(val mApplication: Application, private val mDBVoiceRepository: DBVoiceRepository) : AndroidViewModel(mApplication) {
    val savedRecordFileName: LiveData<String> = mDBVoiceRepository.getTotalOfVoice().map {
        mApplication.getString(R.string.defaultName, (it+1).toString())
    }
}

class DBVoiceRepository private constructor(private val mDBVoiceDao: DBVoiceDao){
    fun getTotalOfVoice() = mDBVoiceDao.getTotalOfVoice()
}

@Dao
interface DBVoiceDao{
   @Query("SELECT count(id) FROM voice_table")
   fun getTotalOfVoice(): LiveData<Long>
}
```

**Add Content**

To Ridcully: Thanks!

I think your way "move all of that into the viewmodel class" is good !

I think it will be OK even if the `filename` is livedata in your Code C, right?

**Code C**

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    filename = dao.getFilename() // without livedata.  I think it will be OK even if the filename is livedata
    voice = getDefaultVoice(...) // also do this in background
    add(voice)
    result.postValue(true)
}
```

Comment: what is the point of using the ViewModel though? 
Remove the viewmodel and you will have the value at once 
I mean you should just change the return type of  the `getTotalOfVoice()` in the DAO to be `Long` instead of `LiveData<Long>`

Comment: Thanks! Normally, Room use background thread to query record asynchronously. I have to get the query result of total records using LiveData or suspend function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you should do Room queries in background to avoid blocking ui thread. But you shouldn't stop there. Do as much work as possible in a background thread. In your case, on button click, start running a background thread that does all the work: getting name from database (with direct query, which is possible now as you are running in background), getting the default voice, and adding it,  to whatever it is you are adding it to.

You should also move all of that into the viewmodel class.

```
btnStop.setOnClickListener {
    viewmodel.stop()
}
```

In viewmodel something like this (java / pseudo code like):

```
void stop() {
    runinbackgroundthread {
        filename = dao.getFilename() // without livedata
        voice = getDefaultVoice(...) // also do this in background
        add(voice)
        // If you want the action to have a reault, observable by ui
        // use a MutableLiveData and set it here, via postValue()
        // as we are still in background thread.
        result.postValue(true)
    }
}
```

On how to actually implement my pseudo code  `runinbackgroundthread` see some official guide here: https://developer.android.com/guide/background/threading

In short, with Kotlin coroutines it should go like this:

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    filename = dao.getFilename() // without livedata
    voice = getDefaultVoice(...) // also do this in background
    add(voice)
    result.postValue(true)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: If you make dao.getFilename() return a LiveData you may have the same problem as before - that you do not get the value right away. It is really no big deal to add another method to the DAO interface. You can also have one, that returns a LiveData and one that returns the value directly - see Room documentation for more on that.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

A simple/tricky/dirty solution would be an empty observe in `onViewCreated` like:

```
mHomeViewModel.savedRecordFileName.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){ }
```

which causes the LiveData to be observed, so it will be queried by Room because it is active and hopefully when you click on the button, the LiveData is filled.

---

---

**Solution 2**

But my favorite approach would be a reactive one. I don't know if you want to take a reactive look toward your code or not, but you can use MediatorLiveData (or take advantage of a library like [this](https://github.com/musichin/ReactiveLiveData)) to solve this situation reactively.
Let there be another LiveData in your VM named `btnStopClicked` and each click changes the value of that LiveData. So, your code may look like this:

```
class FragmentHome : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {        
       ... 
       binding.btnStop.setOnClickListener {
            mHomeViewModel.btnStopClicked.value = null //we don't care about the value
        }
        mHomeViewModel.addVoiceEvent.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
            val aMVoice = getDefaultMVoice(mContext,it)             
            mHomeViewModel.add(aMVoice)   
        }
        ...
        return binding.root
    }

}


class HomeViewModel(val mApplication: Application, private val mDBVoiceRepository: DBVoiceRepository) : AndroidViewModel(mApplication) {
 
    val savedRecordFileName: ... //whatever it was
    val btnStopClicked = MutableLiveData<Any>()

    val addVoiceEvent = savedRecordFileName
        .combineLatestWith(btnStopClicked){srfn, _ -> srfn}
        .toSingleEvent()
}
```

Also do not forget `toSingleEvent` because if you don't turn it into an event, it would get called unintentionally in some situations (look at [this](https://proandroiddev.com/livedata-with-single-events-2395dea972a8)).

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - Code A is better, with extra additions.

As you already know, `LiveData` is not guaranteed to have a non-null value right after instantiation. Ideally, as for best practice, it is good to always treat `LiveData` value as ever changing (i.e - assume direct value access twice will produce different values). This is intended behavior as `LiveData` is designed to be observable instead of you dealing with immediate value.

Hence, listen to the `LiveData` and update your UI accordingly. For instance, disable or hide the *stop button* when there's no data inside it.

```kotlin
mHomeViewModel.savedRecordFileName.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
    binding.btnStop.isEnabled = it != null
}
binding.btnStop.setOnClickListener {
    mHomeViewModel.savedRecordFileName.value?.also {
        val aMVoice = getDefaultMVoice(mContext,it)             
        mHomeViewModel.add(aMVoice)                
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Normally,  Room use background thread to query record asynchronously, it seems that I can't get a query result at once when I use Room , but sometimes I need a query result at once, is there a good way to do it?