# How can I get the query result at once when I use Room?

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I hope to get the total of all records with Room database at once. But, normally Room use background thread to query record asynchronously.

If I use `getTotalOfVoiceAsLiveData()` in Code A, it will return `LiveData<Long>,` you know that LiveData variable is lazy, maybe the result is null.

If I use  `getTotalOfVoice()` in Code A, I will get error because I can't use `return` in `viewModelScope.launch{ }`.

How can I get the total of all records at once with Room database?

**Code A**

```
class HomeViewModel(val mApplication: Application, private val mDBVoiceRepository: DBVoiceRepository) : AndroidViewModel(mApplication) {

    fun getTotalOfVoice():Long {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            return mDBVoiceRepository.getTotalOfVoice()   //It will cause error
        }
    }

    fun getTotalOfVoiceAsLiveData(): LiveData<Long>{
        return mDBVoiceRepository.getTotalOfVoiceAsLiveData() //It's lazy, maybe the result is null.
    }

}


class DBVoiceRepository private constructor(private val mDBVoiceDao: DBVoiceDao){
    suspend  fun getTotalOfVoice() = mDBVoiceDao.getTotalOfVoice()

    fun getTotalOfVoiceAsLiveData() = mDBVoiceDao.getTotalOfVoiceAsLiveData()
}



@Dao
interface DBVoiceDao{
   @Query("SELECT count(id) FROM voice_table")
   suspend fun getTotalOfVoice(): Long

   //When Room queries return LiveData, the queries are automatically run asynchronously on a background thread.
   @Query("SELECT count(id) FROM voice_table")
   fun getTotalOfVoiceAsLiveData(): LiveData<Long>
}
```

**Add content**

To Tobi: Thanks!

*Why it is important to you to get the data directly?*

I need to generate a filename based the total of the records, such as "untitled0", "untitled1", "untitled2"...

If I can get the query result at once, I can use the following code easyly.

**Added again**

I hope to record a voice by filename based the total of query records when I click *Start* button. You know the total of records will change when a reocrd is added or deleted!

**Code B**

```
fun getTotalOfVoice():Long {
    //Get the query result at once
    ...
} 

fun createdFileanme(){
    return "untitled"+getTotalOfVoice().toString()
}

btnStart.setOnClickListener{
    recordVoice(createdFileanme())  //I  will record voice by filename
}

fun addRecord(){
    ...
}

fun deleteRecord(){
    ...
}
```

**New added content**

Thanks!

I think `'You should also move all of that into the viewmodel class, without LiveData '` is good way, you can see Image A and [How can I get the value of a LivaData<String> at once in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64474976/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-a-livadatastring-at-once-in-android-studio) .

Do you agree with it?

**Image A**
[image]

Comment: Does that mean none of the answer below helped so far ?

Comment: Is it possible to say that why do you want the number immediately? I mean what do you want to do with it exactly? or where do you want to use it?

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I hope to get the result at once, but LiveData is lazy

Sorry to tell, but this is how the Room interface is designed.
You are right with the lazyness of the returned LiveData object. But this allows you to handle it on a different thread without having to manually handle different threads.

**Based on your new information!**

You basically have two options:

**A)** you could do the following:

1. load data from Room via LivaData
2. add observer that stores the current total amount
3. when the button is clicked you just read the local copy

In your View: (only one observer and one clickListener)

```
    val totalVoiceCount: long
    val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
    viewModel.getTotalOfVoiceAsLiveData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { totalOfVoice : Long ? ->
            if (totalOfVoice != null)
                totalVoiceCount = totalOfVoice
        })

    btnStart.setOnClickListener{
        viewModel.recordVoice(totalVoiceCount)
    }
```

In your ViewModel: (the logic and everything else)

```
    fun recordVoice(totalVoiceCount : long){
        val fileName = createdFileanme(totalVoiceCount)
        // create your recording // depending on how you do this, it probably runs on a background thread anyways
    }

    fun createdFileName(totalVoiceCount : long){
        return "untitled"+ String.valueOf(totalVoiceCount)
    }
```

This works reliably because the LiveData has enough time to update the local copy of totalVoiceCount before the user has the chance to click the button.

**B)** Based on the answer in your parallel question you can of course outsource even more to a background thread. Then you also have the option to call the DAO query with a non-livedata return (as room returns non-livedata queries only on background threads). Is it worth to implement the threading suggestion of Ridcully? Not possible to answer without knowing what else is going on simultaneously... To me it seems like an overkill, but he is right that the more you do on background threads the better for your refresh rate..

Comment: @HelloCW could you explain, why it is important to you to get the data directly? Maybe we can help to reach your goal even with Livedata and Room. The described intended way should theoretically solve it. If you need further help on setting up your custom SQL database without Room to handle input directly, I could also provide a complete solution..

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: @HelloCW Thanks for elaborating. Could you explain the flow? You read from DB -> you create filename -> you (??) create a file (??)  -> what next? The way you then use/read the file will probably define your way of creating. I still think you can deal with an observer! See more details in my "intended way"

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content again in the question? 
I hope to record a voice by filename based the total of query records when I click Start button. If I use `observer`, add or delete record operation will fire `observer` too.

Comment: @HelloCW Perfect. Seems like we're getting closer. See my update! You basically use a local copy of the totalVoiceCount and update this one in the observer. On button click you then just read from this copy and not from the database itself.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my new added content again in the question?

Comment: @HelloCW Sure, see my updated answer. You can always implement IO threading to reduce workload on the main thread. Is it worth for everything? No. Feeding information back to main thread also has to be handled somehow. See how Ridcully uses LiveData to inform the Mainthread?

Comment: @HelloCW does this help you to get it working? Or do you need other input?

Answer (score 2):

> Question: at once meaning synchronous or what ? if yes, what happens if the function to get the result has to take a longer time? like network call? well you can decide to do that on another thread.

**What I think is for you to use a mutable Object and use the postValue function to dispatch the result to the observers. It should look something like below:**

```
class HomeViewModel(val mApplication: Application, private val mDBVoiceRepository: DBVoiceRepository) : AndroidViewModel(mApplication) {
    private val voices = MutableLiveData<Long>()

    fun getTotalOfVoiceAsLiveData(): LiveData<Long> {
        voices.postValue(mDBVoiceRepository.getTotalOfVoiceAsLiveData().value)
        return voices;
    }
}
```

**Making use of it in your Fragment will look like below:**

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        if (activity != null) {
            val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity())
            viewModel.get(HomeViewModel::class.java).getTotalOfVoiceAsLiveData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { voices: Long ? ->
                voices // Sound of music ? be very free to use ...
            })
        }
    }
```

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can return `Deferred<Long>` from `viewModelScope.async`. I recommend you to use:

```
val deferred = viewModelScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) {
    return@async mDBVoiceRepository.getTotalOfVoice() 
}
val value = deferred.await()
```

await() is suspend

Edit:
If you want to get a getter which will use in your activity or fragment
you need to write a suspend function like this:

```
suspend fun getTotalOfVoice(): Long {
    return viewModelScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) {
                return@async mDBVoiceRepository.getTotalOfVoice()
    }.await()
}
```

But mvvm pattern allows you to create LiveData inside your ViewModel, which gives your fragment an observer.

In view model:

```
private val _totalOfVoiceLD: MutableLiveData<Long> = MutableLiveData()
val totalOfVoiceLD: LiveData<Long>
        get() = _totalOfVoiceLD

fun updateTotalOfVoice() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val totalOfVoice = mDBVoiceRepository.getTotalOfVoice()
            _totalOfVoiceLD.postValue(totalOfVoice)
        }
}
```

and in your fragment:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel.totalOfVoiceLD.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { totalOfVoice ->
            totalOfVoiceTextView.text = totalOfVoice.toString()
        })
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! but your code can't be compiled, I get the error `Suspend function 'await' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend func`

Comment: Of course it doesn't! You need to write it in the viewModelScope.launch block

Comment: Thanks! but `val myValue =  viewModelScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) {deferred.await()}` will return `Deferred<Long>` .

Comment: Thanks! but your code is still to get  the result of total lazy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **coroutineContext.async** to get data from DB and wait for getting it's response with data by using **.await** function for a async dispatch.

```
suspend fun getAllVoices() : Long{
  val awatingResults = viewModelScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) {
      mDBVoiceRepository.getTotalOfVoice() 
  }
  val records = awatingResults.await()
  return records
}
```

It is necessary to call a Suspend function from a coroutine and
**async.await()** is always called in a suspended function so,

```
val voiceLiveData: MutableLiveData<Long> = MutableLiveData()

fun getAllVoicesFromDB() {
   viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
       voiceLiveData.postValue(mDBVoiceRepository.getTotalOfVoice())
   }
}
```

Now call it where ever you want to get your voice data from database and also remember do your further work inside your **voiceLiveData** **observer** where you get your response of voices :)

Comment: Thanks! I hope to get the result at once, but LiveData is lazy.

Answer (score 0):

Live data is designed to be lazy, when the value of the live data changes internally it emits and wherever you are observing it, the onChange function will be invoked. It is designed to fire and forget.
Because room uses background thread to run the query.
You can't expect live data to behave like sharedpreference where you store key value pair.
If you want to achieve something like that.
I would suggest you to use
Paper Db or Realm.

Answer (score 0):

If you need your Room result synchronously, your code should be execute in IO thread. In case of coroutines, you can use `Dispatchers.IO`. Your code can be changed to this to pass the error.

```
class HomeViewModel(val mApplication: Application, private val mDBVoiceRepository: DBVoiceRepository) : AndroidViewModel(mApplication) {

    fun getTotalOfVoice():Long {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { // here
            return mDBVoiceRepository.getTotalOfVoice()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must run the queries in the main thread, then:

1. Allow android room to execute queries in main thread.

   ```kotlin
    val dbInstance = Room
        .databaseBuilder(ctx, YourDBClass::class.java, "YourDBName")
        .allowMainThreadQueries()
        .build()
   ```
2. Define the dao method as follows

   ```
   @Dao
   interface DBVoiceDao{
      @Query("SELECT count(id) FROM voice_table")
      fun getTotalOfVoice(): Long
   }
   ```
3. Access the method in the repository

   ```kotlin
   fun getTotalOfVoice():Long {
       return dao.getTotalOfVoice()        
   }
   ```